# TensorFlow: read a frozen model, add operations, then save to a new frozen model

Tags: tensorflow

I am sorry in advance if the title does not reflect exactly my problem (I think it does, but I'm not sure), which I describe below.

I am working on converting a Yolo object detection model to a TensorFlow frozen model `.pb` and then to use that model for prediction on mobile phones.

I have successfully obtained a working `.pb` model (i.e. a frozen graph from Yolo's graph). But since the outputs of the network (there are two of them) are not the bounding boxes, I have to write a function for conversion (this part is not my question, I already have a working function for this task):

```
def get_boxes_from_output(outputs_of_the_graph, anchors,
        num_classes, input_image_shape,
        score_threshold=score, iou_threshold=iou)
    """
    Apply some operations on the outputs_of_the_graph to obtain bounding boxes information
    """
    return boxes, scores, classes
```

So the pipeline is simple: I have to load the `pb` model, then throw the image data to it to get two outputs, then from these two outputs, I apply the above function (that contains tensor operations) to obtain bounding boxes information. The code look like this:

```
model_path = 'model_data/yolo.pb'
class_names = _get_class('model_data/classes.txt')
anchors = _get_anchors('model_data/yolo_anchors.txt')

score = 0.25
iou = 0.5

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(model_path, 'rb') as fid:
        graph_def.ParseFromString(fid.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

        # Get the input and output nodes (there are two outputs)
        l_input = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_1:0')
        l_output = [detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('conv2d_10/BiasAdd:0'),
                    detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('conv2d_13/BiasAdd:0')]

        #initialize_all_variables
        tf.global_variables_initializer()

        # Generate output tensor targets for filtered bounding boxes.
        input_image_shape = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=(2, ))
        training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='training')

        boxes, scores, classes = get_boxes_from_output(l_output, anchors,
        len(class_names), input_image_shape,
        score_threshold=score, iou_threshold=iou)


    image = Image.open('./data/image1.jpg')
    image = preprocess_image(image)
    image_data = np.array(image, dtype='float32')
    image_data = np.expand_dims(image_data, 0)  # Add batch dimension.

    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

    # Run the session to get the output bounding boxes
    out_boxes, out_scores, out_classes = sess.run(
    [boxes, scores, classes],
    feed_dict={
        l_input: image_data,
        input_image_shape: [image.size[1], image.size[0]],
        training: False
    })
    # Now how do I save a new model that outputs directly [boxes, scores, classes]
```

**Now my question is how do I save a new `.pb` model from the session, so that I can load it again elsewhere and it can directly outputs `boxes, scores, classes`?**

I hope the question is clear enough.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: please provide your `get_boxes_from_output` function. I am trying to do something similar and have problems understanding the output of the model.

Answer (score 3):

#### Add nodes and save to a frozen model

Once you have added the new ops, you need to write the new graph using `tf.train.write_graph`:

```
boxes, scores, classes = get_boxes_from_output()
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def,save_dir,'new_cnn_weights.pb')
```

Then you need to freeze the above graph using the `freeze_graph` utility. Make sure the `output_node_names` are set to `boxes, scores, classes` as shown below:

```
# Freeze graph
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
import os

input_graph_path = os.path.join(save_dir, 'new_cnn_weights.pb')
input_saver_def_path = ''
input_binary = False
output_node_names = 'boxes, scores, classes'
restore_op_name = ''
filename_tensor_name = ''
output_graph_path = os.path.join(save_dir, 'new_frozen_cnn_weights.pb')
clear_devices = False
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(save_dir, 'test_model')
freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path, input_saver_def_path,
                      input_binary, checkpoint_path, output_node_names,
                      restore_op_name, filename_tensor_name,
                      output_graph_path, clear_devices, '')
```

#### Check the optimized graph

```
#Load the new optimized graph and check whether the output is consistent,
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.gfile.GFile(save_dir+'new_frozen_cnn_weights.pb', 'rb') as f:
   graph_def_optimized = tf.GraphDef()
   graph_def_optimized.ParseFromString(f.read())

G = tf.Graph()

with tf.Session(graph=G) as sess:
   boxes,scores,classes = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def_optimized, return_elements=['boxes:0', 'scores:0', 'classes:0'])
   print('Operations in Optimized Graph:')
   print([op.name for op in G.get_operations()]) 
   x = G.get_tensor_by_name('import/import/input:0')
   print(sess.run([boxes, scores, classes], feed_dict={x: np.expand_dims(img, 0)}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't have any checkpoint so I couldn't perform the `freeze_graph()` step :( The first step `tf.train.write_graph()` only created a new `.pb` file, there is no checkpoint. I aslo tried `tf.train.Saver()` but it says 'ValueError: No variables to save'. Thus, I thought the model may already be frozen so I tried reading `new_cnn_weights.pb` directly using your last part of code, but then obtained "DecodeError: Error parsing message". Thanks again for your help!